# Как повторить код в цикле?

Tags: python, mouse-event, mousemove

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно повторить записанные движения мыши в цикле?
В качестве основы выбрал:

```
import mouse
# record until you click right
events = mouse.record()
# replay these events
mouse.play(events[:-1])
```

Хочу воспроизвести записанные через events = mouse.record() движения в бесконечном цикле с промежутком 5 сек.
Через "while True" не смог корректно повторить

Comment: почему не смогли ? покажите неудачную попытку вместе с полным текстом ошибки.

Answer (score 1):

Видно, с отступами проблема была.
Сделал следующим образом:

```
import mouse
import time
# record until you click right
events = mouse.record()
while True:
    # sec sleep
    time.sleep(5)
        # replay these events
    mouse.play(events[:-1])
```